# Differential diagnosis for shortness of breath from anxiety

Tags: psychiatry

Unexplained or difficult to explain shortness of breath seems to be blamed on anxiety very frequently despite lack of diagnostic evidence, especially in individuals with psychiatric conditions. This is not helpful to people that experience shortness of breath as a side effect of medication or from other causes that have not been identified.

How can one make sure that the diagnosis (and vast symptoms) of anxiety isn't being applied too liberally and that the patient receives the best possible diagnosis/care (especially when there are concurrent psychiatric conditions)?

Comment: I vote to close this question, because it would be a better fit on Health.SE

Comment: @RobinKramer It's directly related to psychiatry so is on-topic.

Comment: As written this is too broad. "Unexplained or difficult to explain" needs specific examples. Basically you seem to be asking how shortness of breath is diagnosed, without giving an example or any reason to believe there is any related difficulty in doing so.

Comment: @user3169 I guess a mod can vote to move the question. But I disagree and see nothing wrong with asking how prove a symptom is caused by anxiety. Anxiety is a very large umbrella term for anything that causes fear/unease, etc... it's a catch all for anything a doctor cannot explain. Blaming a symptom that cannot be explained on anxiety without proof, is a guess. A guess that can very likely result in no treatment at all. I'm pointing that out and asking how one could clarify a diagnosis. I specifically ask about shortness of breath as an example. Still too broad?

Comment: Are you asking what diagnostic process would be followed when the "usual" diagnostics don't work? Then, what is "usual"? By definition you can't make a [*diagnosis*](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/diagnosis) without evidence of some kind.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I vaguely remember that almost all disorder's criteria in DSM includes points such as "...not related to any other medical/health condition or effects of any drugs, substances, or medication" Which make me believe that whoever is creating the diagnosis would require a valid medical-examination report from the patient

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you combine the reading of the [DSM](http://www.dsm5.org/about/Pages/Default.aspx) with a pharmaceutical book such as the [BNF](https://www.bnf.org/products/bnf-online/) you will get the desired results when you know what your client is prescribed.